# Determine server requirements for PHP application

Tags: php, server, performance-testing, stress-testing

I'm currently working on a web app and if all goes to plan, it could very well grow extremely quickly. This is the first app I'm building where server requirements are a big question to me. What can I do to determine how much bandwidth, ram, and processing power I'm going to need?

Is there a specific term to what I'm trying to find out here? I've heard of stress testing but I'm not sure that's what this is.

Any help would be great.

Comment: stress testing is basically to simulate a ton of operations on your app and check if it can hold it. Instead of searching for PHP performance, look for apache2, nginx and mysql performance calculations. That can give you an estimate for the number of users and operations.

Comment: Better yet, design the application so that instead of scaling your server vertically [bigger server] you scale it horizontally [more servers]. Because 1. There's a limit to how big you can make a single server. 2. The price of a server generally scales up faster than the resources. Then you start with one or two small servers, bolt on extras as you need, and potentially even scale down if demand slumps.

Comment: @Sammitch So I assume under that model you still have a single "large" database server and then you just have basically load balanced instances of your site?

Comment: Scaling the persistence layer horizontally is difficult, but not impossible. It entirely depends on what kind of data you're storing, how you store it, and how you query it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apache jMeter http://jmeter.apache.org/ for load/stress testing.

Here is a tutorial which might help you.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-jmeter-to-perform-load-testing-on-a-web-server